# Cost Optimization across Different Suppliers for a Product

Tags: math, optimization, dynamic-programming, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I've this following optimization problem. A company produces a product, say Big A. To produce this product, it requires 5 processes. (Please find the detail table below). For each process, there are number of supplier that supply raw material for that particular process. E.g. For process 1, there are 3 supplier 1,2 & 3.

The constrain for the CEO of this company,say C, is that for each process the CEO has to purchase supplies from Supplier 1 first, then for additional supplies from 2nd Supplier and so on.

The optimization problem is C wants 700 units for total material to produce for 1 unit of Big A then how will he do it at minimum cost. How the optimization will change if the amount of units require increases to 1500 units.

I'll be grateful if I get the solution of this answer. But if somebody can suggest me some reference regarding this problem it will be a great help too. I'm mainly using R software here.

```
Process Supplier    Cost    Units   Cumm_Cost   Cumm_Unit
     1     1         10     100       10          100
     1     2         20     110       30          210
     1     3         10     200       40          410
     2     1         20     100       20          100
     2     2         30     150       50          250
     2     3         10     150       60          400
     3     1         40     130       40          130
     3     2         30     140       70          270
     3     3         50     120      120          390
     4     1         20     120       20          120
     4     2         40     120       60          240
     4     3         20     180       80          420
     5     1         30     180       30          180
     5     2         10     160       40          320
     5     3         30     140       70          460
```

Regards,

Comment: " for each process the CEO has to purchase supplies from Supplier 1 first, then for additional supplies from 2nd Supplier and so on. " -- In that case, the decision for the CEO is already fixed, isn't it? There seems to be no choice, and no optimization is needed.

Comment: No. He has to take units from 1st suppliers. But he can change the composition of units per process. Eg. Say he choose 2 suppliers from process 1, 2 from process 2. And 1 each from other 3 process. He will chose number of suppliers from each process such that total cost is minimum and produce 700 units.

Comment: OK. Please define your decision variables so that others can really help. As it stands, your question isn't really clear, and suggesting general linear or non-linear optimization techniques wouldn't help you solve your problem.

Comment: Could you please let me know what do you mean by saying "define your decision variable."? My problem is minimize cost, such that I can produce 700 units.

Comment: See e.g. https://www.courses.psu.edu/for/for466w_mem14/Ch11/HTML/Sec1/ch11sec1_Vars.htm There may be better sources. You want to minimize the cost, that's the objective function. Roughly speaking, you need variables for that function to properly define the problem.

Comment: Thanks Ting L for all your comments and suggestion. I'm having this problem of creating variables and functions. If I could have created them it would be far easier to solve this problem. But I'll try it. Thanks for the resource.

Comment: (a) Do you require a minimum amount produced from each process? (b) `has to purchase supplies from Supplier 1 first, then for additional supplies from 2nd Supplier and so on` do you mean that for each process the *quantity* purchased from supplier 1 should be higher than the quantity purchased from supplier 2 and so on? (c) is column `Units` an upper bound on the number of units that can be purchased per supplier per process? (d) can you confirm that 700 is the raw material from all processes and not from each process?

Comment: Thanks Ioannis for your interest in this question! Answers for your queries a) No. We don't need to produce minimum amount to be produced for each process. b) No. Supplier 1 can provide certain number of items for each process. Bu that number of item can be greater than or less than the subsequent supplier. c) Yes. Actually those are each supplier maximum number of units that can be supplied by him and unit cost of that supplier. d) 700 is the overall number of units of raw materials required in the entire process. Not just for each process. Hope this will help.

Comment: @user697363, thank you for the follow up! A couple of more clarifications and hopefully I will be able to post my model. (a) Ultimately, not having a minimum amount means that a process might not be used at all. If this is the case, I would suggest changing `it requires 5 processes` to `up to 5 processes can be used` (but not necessarily all 5 of them). (b) Then I assume that we purchase from supplier 2 only when we have bought the max quantity allowed from supplier 1 for a certain process? Else we can buy 1 item from supplier 1 and then 110 from supplier 2 (for process 1 for example).

Comment: @Ioannis:Please find the answers to your questions, a) We need to produce minimum amount for each process. E.g. we need to produce atleast 1 unit of each process. Otherwise the optimization will become very straight forward. Use all the raw units for the production of only 1 process. b) Yes. Eg. for process 1, CEO have to purchase the entire amount of 100 units from Supplier 1. Only when he will require more amount for process 1, he can go to Supplier 2. Suppose he requires 200 units for process 1. He will purchase 100 units from supplier 1. And then purchase another 100 units from supplier 2.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Note that even without requiring a minimum amount of 1 item from each process, the solution is not so straightforward :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will start by solving the specific problem that you have posted and then will demonsrate how to formulate the problem more abstractively. For simplicity, I will use `Excel`'s `Solver` add-in to solve the problem, but any configuration of a modeling language (such as [AIMMS](http://www.aimms.com/), [AMPL](http://ampl.com/), [LINGO](http://www.lindo.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2&Itemid=10), [OPL](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/modeling/), [MOSEL](http://www.fico.com/en/products/fico-xpress-optimization-suite/) and numerous others) with a solver ([CPLEX](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/), [GUROBI](http://www.gurobi.com/), [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/), [CBC](http://www.coin-or.org/projects/Cbc.xml) and numerous others) can be used. If you would like to use `R`, there exists an [lpSolve package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/index.html) that calls the [lpSolve solver](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/) (which is not the best one in the word to be honest, but it is free of charge).

Note that for "real" (large scale) integer problems, [the commercial solvers CPLEX, GUROBI and XPRESS perform a lot better than others](http://www.statistik.tuwien.ac.at/forschung/CS/CS-2012-1complete.pdf). The first completely free solver that performs decently in most tests (including [Hans Mittelman's page](http://plato.asu.edu/bench.html)) is CBC. CBC can be hooked up in excel and solve the built-in solver model without restrictions in the number of constraints or variables, by using [this add-in](http://opensolver.org/). Therefore, assuming that most CPU is going to be spent by the optimization algorithm, using CBC/OpenSolver seems like an efficient choice.

**SPREADSHEET SETUP**

I follow some conventions for convenience:

- Decision variable cells are marked Green.
- Constraints are marked red.
- Data are marked grey.
- Objective function is marked blue.

First, lets augment the table you presented as follows:

[image]

The added columns explained briefly:

- **Selected?**: equals 1 if the `(Process, Supplier)` combo is allowed to produced a positive quantity, zero otherwise.
- **Quantity**: the quantity produced, defined for each  `(Process, Supplier)` combo.
- **Max Quantity?**: Equals 1 if the Suppliers produces the maximum amount of units for that particular Process.
- **Quantity UB**: equals **Units** * **Selected?**. This makes the upper bound either equal to Units, when the Supplier is allowed to produce this Process, or zero otherwise.
- **Quantity LB**: equals **Units** * **Max Quantity?**. This is to ensure that whenever the **Max Quantity?** column is 1, the produced quantity will be equal to **Units**.
- **Selection**: For the 1st supplier, it equals 0. For the 2nd and 3rd suppliers, it equals the **Max Quantity?** of the previous supplier (row) minus the **Selected?** of the current supplier (row).

A screenshot with formulas:

[image]

There exist two more constraints:

1. There must be at least one item produced from each process and
2. The total number of items should be 700 (or later 1,500).

Here is their setup:

[image]

and here are the formulas:

[image]

In brief, we use `SUMIF` to sum the quantities that are specific to each supplier, which we are going to constrain to be more than 1 item for each process.

To finish the spreadsheet setup, we need to calculate the objective function, namely the cost of the allocation. This is easily done by taking the `SUMPRODUCT` of columns **Quantity** and **Cost**. Note that the cumulative quantities are derived data and not very useful in the current context.

After the above steps, the spreadsheet looks like below:

[image]

**SOLVER MODEL**

For the solver model we need to declare

- The Objective
- The Decisions
- The Constraints
- The Solver (and tweak some parameters if necessary).

For ease of exposition, I have given each range the name of its header. The solver model looks as follows:

[image]

It should all be explanatory, except possibly the `Selected >= 0` part. The column selected equals the difference between the binary `max Quantity` of the previous supplier minus the `Selected` of the current supplier. `Selected >= 0` => `max Quantity` of previous supplier >= `Selected` of current supplier. Therefore, if the previous supplier does not produce at max quantity (binary = 0), the current supplier cannot produce.

Then we need to make sure that the solver setting are OK:

[image]

and solve the problem.

**Solution for `req = 700`** :

[image]

As we see, the model tries to avoid procedures 3 and 5 as much as possible, and satisfies the constraint "at least 1 item per process" by picking up exactly 1 item for processes 3 and 5. The objective function value is `11,710`.

**Solution for `req = 1,500`** :

[image]

Here we need more capacity, but yet process 3 seems expensive and the model tries to avoid it by allocating whatever is necessary (just 1 unit to supplier 1).

I hope this helps. The spreadsheet can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mugcr6lh63gjwbg/Book1.xlsx). I include the definition of the mathematical model below, in case you would like to transfer it to another language.

**MATHEMATICAL FORMULATION**

A formal definition of your problem is as follows.

**SETS**:

[image]

**PARAMETERS**:
[image]

**Decisions**:
[image]

**Objective**:

[image]

**Constraints**:
[image]

**Constraint explanation**:

C1: A supplier cannot produce anything from a process if he has not been allocated to that process.

C2: If a supplier's maximum indicator is set to 1, then the production variable should be the maximum possible.

C3: We cannot select supplier `s` for process `p` if we have not produced the max quantity available from the previous supplier `s_[-1]`.

C4: We need to produce at least 1 item from each process.

C5: the total production from all processes and suppliers should equal the required amount.

Comment: Thank you Ioannis for your Wonderful solution. I really like the way you gave the detail answer. Now, if I need to tweak my requirement a bit I can. And I also know to tools to look for to. I just want to know how you calculated column "Selected?" & "Quantity". These 2 columns are most important for rest of the calculations. Thank you again :).

Comment: @user697363 your welcome! The green cells are calculated automatically by the solver when you hit the "solve" button on the lower right of the solver box. Under the hood, the solver invokes optimisation algorithms that try many different combinations of eligible numbers of the columns Selected, Quantity. And Max Quantity and picks up the feasible combination that gives the minimum total cost. You can delete the contents or put any number there, as soon as you hit solve, the optimal solution will pop up.

Comment: Note that the way I formulated the problem the solver can actually check that a solution is optimal or not, and for small problems like this it usually returns a guaranteed optimal solution. For other classes of problems (with non convex structures and non linear) such a guarantee does not exist, and the solver result might depend on the initial values of the green cells (decision variables)

Comment: Thanks Ioannis! This will help.

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you should look at the simplex algorithm (or some existing implementation of it).
Wikipedia has a fairly nice description of the algorithm, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm

Comment: this will not work using simplex method. Because we have to cummulate cost & units here.